# Highlight a specific phrase in any emacs buffer, regardless of mode

Tags: highlighting

I would like to be able to highlight a particular phrase (in my case: `@dakrone`) in every emacs buffer, regardless of the mode (it's fine if it doesn't work in `fundamental-mode`). I know of something like:

```
(defun eos/add-watchwords ()
  "Highlight FIXME and TODO in code"
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil '(("\\<\\(TODO\\(?:(.*)\\)?:?\\)\\>"  1 'warning prepend)
         ("\\<\\(FIXME\\(?:(.*)\\)?:?\\)\\>" 1 'error prepend))))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'eos/add-watchwords)
```

But I haven't gotten something like that to be applied globally instead of having to manually add every mode I want to highlight in. Is there a way do do this?

Comment: Not all modes use `font-lock`; e.g., `org-agenda-mode` uses text-properties.  Font-lock and text-properties do not play well together.  A third option is to use overlays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use library [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el) to highlight any text in any buffer, using either text properties or overlays.  The highlighting can be independent of font-locking or be controlled by `font-lock-mode`.

There are many ways to highlight, and your question is not very specific.
See [Highlight Library](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after-change-major-mode-hook` to generalize modes, eg:

```el
(defun eos/add-watchwords ()
  "Highlight FIXME and TODO in code"
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil '(("\\<\\(TODO\\(?:(.*)\\)?:?\\)\\>"  1 'warning prepend)
         ("\\<\\(FIXME\\(?:(.*)\\)?:?\\)\\>" 1 'error prepend))))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
      (eos/add-watchwords))))
```